# Reading from internal flash in a microcontroller

Tags: c, flash, microcontroller

I am trying to code a TZ series microcontroller from Toshiba to collect the data from sensor via I2C and store data into internal NOR flash with time stamp every second. I am facing a problem in reading the value from the flash which is the data from the sensor stored. My code is as follows,

```
   while(1)
   {
     if (input == 'a')
     {

         read_sens();
         sram_area[0] = (int)value;
         vTaskDelay(1000);

       rtn = drv_info->WriteData(WRITE_ADDRESS, sram_area, sizeof(sram_area));
       print_sp(PREF"DATA WRITE rtn= %d data=0x%02x\r\n",rtn,*sram_area); 
         print_sp(PREF "MEM VALUE  0x%08x\r\n", (ptr+=2));
     }

     if (input == 'b')
     {
        rtn = drv_info->ReadData(WRITE_ADDRESS, hts_measurement1 , 1);

       print_sp(PREF "DATA READ  rtn=%d  %d  \r\n",rtn, hts_measurement1[0]);

      //print_sp(PREF "MEM VALUE  0x%08x\r\n", (ptr+=1));
      vTaskDelay(1000);
     }
   }
```

Both variables `sram_area` and `hts_measurement1` are global arrays and are of type `uint8_t` . varialble Value is simple sensor data, which would keep on updating every second and is of type float. Variable `rtn` represents a return value (either 0 or 1) from the function WriteData and ReadData and is of type `uint8_t`. If I try to read the data simultaneously with write then I can read the value properly. But the idea is to first write the data to flash first and then read it when required. I request some one to help me out on this.

I am using FREE RTOS and Toshiba series microcontroller.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards, 
Nitin

Comment: Not very clear, also, 'sram_area' is a misleading name for a flash sector:(

Comment: It is just a variable with a name given.

Comment: What is the problem? Can you show us what is printed by `print_sp`?

Comment: Did you notice that you write `sizeof(sram_area)` bytes, while you read only one bytes?

Comment: It will print the return value as '0' (which means success) and the sram_area  value which is in turn the sensor value. sizeof(sram_area) is just 1 byte.

Comment: Show the definitions of `sram_area` and `hts_measurement1`.  If the size of `sram_area` is one byte then shouldn't you cast `value` to `uint8_t` rather than `int`?  What is the range of `value`?  Do you need to erase the flash before writing it?  You print the write data in hex but the read data in decimal.

Comment: Can you show what you written - and what is been read?  from float to uint8!? what is the range of `value` ? And what is `(ptr+=2)` in `print_sp` statement ?

Comment: You are writing to same address location in every loop, so it is getting over written with new value.  That is the reason, if you write and then read, your values are correct!
How many sensor values are you writing ? why are you not increment the nor flasg address location?

Comment: @Sudhee How i am suppose to increment that address? I thought By increment of ptr which is assigned to write address would do this job.

Comment: You have not provided the full code here, not sure whats happening in `WriteData` function or other area of code. I also asked question about `(ptr+=2)` what it means, no answer for that as well. But with your **increment of ptr which is assigned to write address would do this job** answer, i can guess that changing to `rtn = drv_info->WriteData(ptr, sram_area, 1);` would work. if you post your all relevant code here, i can suggest you further.

Comment: @Sudhee Please find the full code here. https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArltqXFAt4b_gfMP-0s0cmklrKE-6g

Answer (score 0):

I have tried give the possible implementation, but i have not compiled or validated on board as I donot have the board.

```
#define WRITE_ADDRESS            0x0007fff8     // NOR Flash address 
#define DATA_SIZE                0x02
#Define NO_OF_SAMPLES            10             // Change depending on your requirement and FLASH Size
#define DEBUG_NOR                1              // Enabled for debug purpose

float temperature = 0.0;
ARM_NOR_STATUS rtn;
uint8_t *ptr = (uint8_t *)WRITE_ADDRESS;
int32_t temp_i;
uint8_t sram_area[DATA_SIZE]={0x00,0x00};


void tmp006_demo_task(void *pvParameters)
{
    char input;
    uint32_t i;
    unsigned short Temp =0;

    #ifdef NOR_USE_SDMAC
        Driver_SDMAC.Initialize();
        Driver_SDMAC.PowerControl(ARM_POWER_FULL);
    #endif

    rtn = drv_info->Initialize(0);

    rtn = drv_info->PowerControl(ARM_POWER_FULL);

    input = prompt_console("select :");

    if ((input >= 'A') && (input <= 'Z'))
    {
        input = input + ('a' - 'A');
    }
    while(1)
    {
        if (input == 'a')
        {
            ptr = (uint8_t *)WRITE_ADDRESS;
            for (i=0; i < NO_OF_SAMPLES;i++)
            {
                #ifdef (DEBUG_NOR)
                    sram_area[0]  =  i*20;  //Some random number for only debugging purpose
                    sram_area[1]  =  i*15;
                #else
                    read_temp();            //Probable implementation  17.25 value is stored as 1725 
                    Temp = (unsigned short)(temperature * 100);
                    sram_area[0] = 0xFF & Temp;
                    sram_area[1] = 0xFF & (Temp >> 8);

                #endif

                vTaskDelay(1000);

                rtn = drv_info->WriteData(ptr, sram_area, 2);       //I'm hardcoding the size to 2
                if (rtn != ARM_NOR_OK)
                {
                    print_sp(PREF "Writing to NOR Flash Failed \r\n"); 
                    break;
                }
                print_sp(PREF "DATA WRITE        rtn=%d  data=0x%x 0x%x \r\n",  rtn, sram_area[0], sram_area[1]); 

                ptr = ptr+2; //Increment the pointer  
                             //Am Assuming atleast you have 20bytes in Nor flash that can be used                                

            }

            input =0 ;  //Making sure again it is not entering into the loop

        }

        if (input == 'b')
        {
            ptr = (uint8_t *)WRITE_ADDRESS;
            for (i=0; i < NO_OF_SAMPLES;i++)
            {
                vTaskDelay(1000);
                rtn = drv_info->ReadData(ptr, sram_area , 2);
                if (rtn != ARM_NOR_OK)
                {
                    print_sp(PREF "Reading to NOR Flash Failed \r\n"); 
                    break;
                }
                print_sp(PREF "DATA Read        rtn=%d  data=0x%x 0x%x \r\n",  rtn, sram_area[0], sram_area[1]); 

                ptr = ptr+2;

            }
            input = 0;          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nithin N - Please compile and correct the compiler errors if any

Comment: It has an error across `ptr` stating that `uint8_t *` is incompatible with `uint32_t`, because of casting `ptr` to `WRITE_ADDRESS`. The function takes parameters `WriteData( uint32_t addr, uint8_t *data, uint32_t size);`